# Binary Search in D 2.0 (Phobos)?

Tags: binary-search, d, phobos

Is it just me, or is there no binary search function in Phobos? I have a pre-sorted array that I want to search with my own comparator function, but I can't find anything in std.algorithms or std.containers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `SortedRange` from `std.range`:

Cribbed from http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_range.html#SortedRange:

```
auto a = [ 1, 2, 3, 42, 52, 64 ];
auto r = assumeSorted(a);
assert(r.canFind(3));
assert(!r.canFind(32));
```

Comment: Ah, you have to use "assumeSorted"... didn't expect that, thanks! :)

Comment: `find()` (and thus `canFind()`) is actually pretty smart, using different algorithms based on what type input its given. In order for binary search to work, the data has to be sorted, so `assumeSorted()` makes it so that it is, and then `find()` and `canFind()` are smart enough to know that binary search is the best search then, and that's what they do.

Comment: It's not intuitive at all though if you are simply trying to do a binary search.

Comment: It's late and I'm tired, but I suspect the design is good, I mean, it seems cool to bring strong typing to the concept of sortedness, and to separate 'what you want to do' from 'how it gets done'. D just needs a solid body of questions and answers like this one so that people can learn these things quickly with Google.